# Mixing VB.net Web Forms application project with C# Web forms application project in Same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am new in .NET world and very new to this kind of configuration and stuck to start the changes requested by business user.

We have VB.net web form apps which was created long time back. We were recently requested to add few more functionality and the team wants to add those new pages as C# webform. I know it is possible to have many projects in one solution. Now, I need some guidance on how to integrate those two projects.

I have added a new asp.net C# web form project under the solution where the old vb.net project exists and added aspx page in C# webform project.

Now from VB.net project I want to redirect users to this c# webform project and Viceversa.

How can we achieve this, what changes do I need to make in configurations? Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: Each WebForms project represents a single web application, and although you can use multiple applications in IIS and compose them into something that looks like a single web site, this is not what you're talking about. Your web application project is going to be in *one* .NET language, either C# or VB.NET. If you can separate some of that code into a class library project that the web application can reference, then it can be in either language. But your question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the post and yes, I was wondering if there is a way without creating a class library, so I can manage the business layers and data access layers in the C# project as sooner or later the whole application will be converting to MVC or C# webforms.

Comment: I think this is not all that of a good idea. If you are to build some routines, some class(s) with business logic? Then sure - write those new bits and parts in c#, and then simple reference those new class(s) and bits of code you create. However, mixing the UI and forms, and attempting to mix c# forms, and vb.net forms? That is a really bad idea - it just is. You can write and create say some class objects in c# in a separate c# applcation. And you can again reference those code and bits and parts from vb.net. However, a seamless intermixing of the forms? No, that's more pain then the results

Comment: If you already have data access and business logic as separate layers, convert those first. If they're not already class libraries, move them over, and then translate them. That's your best route: thin VB.NET web application, with all the bulk in C# class libraries. Then go to MVC; don't just move to Web Forms with C#. Make improvements, not lateral moves.

Comment: so, if you build and write the c# project and code - as all near classes, then you can consume that code (and forms) in the vb.net project. But, you be creating instances of that object in the vb.net project, and then methods of that class can do things like say display a form. But, really, too much handstands.

Comment: seeing this is a asp.net application? Well, you can intermix if you using a asp.net web site, but if you using a asp.net web site applcation, then no, it too messy to attempt this idea.

Comment: I think. I will suggest dropping the idea of intermixing to the team and see how it goes with them. Thanks Albert and Madreflection.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to call C# web form pages from VB.NET Web Form.

For doing so, in the C# web form project build events property. We wrote some command line

[image]

Then added that project as a reference in main vb project. This let me call the pages.